# What is the purpose of the tilde in this situation?

Tags: c#

What could be the purpose of the tilde in this code block?

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      return ~this.DimensionId.Id ^ this.ElementId.Id;
    }
```

**^ Operator (C# Reference)**
Visual Studio 2010
Binary ^ operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, ^ computes the bitwise exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool operands, ^ computes the logical exclusive-or of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if exactly one of its operands is true.

**~ Operator (C# Reference)**
Visual Studio 2010
The ~ operator performs a bitwise complement operation on its operand, which has the effect of reversing each bit. Bitwise complement operators are predefined for int, uint, long, and ulong.

The ~ (tilde) operator performs a bitwise complement on its single integer operand. (The ~ operator is therefore a unary operator, like ! and the unary -, &, and * operators.) Complementing a number means to change all the 0 bits to 1 and all the 1s to 0s

What would be a reason **why** it would be used in this context (as opposed to simply excluding it)?

Comment: The xor operator tends to produce poor hash distribution if the values are small.  Flipping the bits can change that.  Odds that this actually works out are not good.  Multiplying one by a prime and adding works better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's simply one way of generating a hash code. I'm not a huge fan of XORs in hash codes unless you want something that's order-independent, but it's a reasonable way of flipping bits in a reasonably arbitrary but repeatable way.

Basically you've got two 32-bit values here, which you need to combine in some form to create another 32-bit value. The code *could* have just XORed the values together without any bitwise complement:

```
return DimensionId.Id ^ ElementId.Id;
```

... but that would always give zero for cases where `ElementId.Id == DimensionId.Id`, which probably isn't ideal. On the other hand, we now always end up with -1 if the two IDs are the same, as noted in comments (doh!). On the other hand, it makes the pair {6, 4} have a different hash code to {4, 6} whereas a simple XOR doesn't... it makes the ordering important, in other words. Again, that could be important if your *real* identifiers are likely to be taken from a relatively small pool.

The XOR itself makes sure that a change to *any* bit in *either* ID makes a difference to the final hashcode.

Personally I normally follow Josh Bloch's pattern from effective Java, e.g.

```
unchecked
{
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * 31 + DimensionId.Id;
    hash = hash * 31 + ElementId.Id;
    return hash;
}
```

... but that's just because of some of the properties of hashing that way<sup>1</sup>, and it doesn't make the implementation you've shown "wrong" in any sense.

---

<sup>1</sup> It seems to work pretty well at producing distinct values in a number of common scenarios. Obviously it can't prevent hash collisions, but *if* your IDs are actually generated from a sequence of 1, 2, 3... then this will do better at real-life collisions that an XOR. I did see a web page analyzing this approach and which numbers work well etc, but I can't remember where.

Comment: Jon Skeet- Completely Ignorant Question: what's the alternative/better approach to XOR in hash codes? XOR being the only way I know to do it well.

Comment: @RitchMelton: I was probably putting my preferred code in while you commented... see the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Jon - did I miss these operators in C# in Depth 2nd Ed?  In any event thanks for the info!

Comment: However, using `~` will always give -1 for cases where `ElementId.Id == DimensionId.Id`.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Nope, I didn't cover these in C# in Depth as they haven't changed since C# 1.

Comment: @Jon - Please post the page if you find it. I'm Binging for it too ;)